# What does a DVI-VGA adapter output?

Tags: vga, dvi, adapter

I have a DVI-VGA Adapter:

[image]

If I have a PC that only has a DVI port, and a monitor that only has a VGA port, what will be the output? DVI or VGA? And what if that was reversed? (I.e. Monitor only takes DVI and PC only takes VGA)

Comment: which type of [DVI port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface) does your computer have? as for the reverse, I don't think it would be possible without some reverse male/female adapters - which would make any such configuration unsupported by both the source and the receiver, and make any guess as to if it works or not very specific.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Both the PC and the Monitor have female inputs.

Comment: DVI-D is a digital-only version of DVI, and will not work with any passive VGA adapter, such as the one in your picture - DVI-A is analogue only DVI, and will work, as it's the same signal, only over a different pinout, which the adapter converts. DVI-I can carry either digital or analogue signals, and thus would work, provided that the source can also produce an analogue signal. For the reverse, you would need to find a receiver that can accept a DVI-A signal. In order to answer your question of "what will be the output", the specific type of DVI that you have needs to be given.

Comment: Well the current DVI cable is a Single Link (DVI-I), while the adapter has a DVI-A. So you're saying that DVI-A and VGA are essentially the same thing?

Comment: Yes I am saying DVI-A and VGA are essntially the same thing (minus the physical pinout, but same signal), and that specific combination should work (DVI-I cable + DVI-A outout) (within the limits of VGA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final output (with the adapter) would be VGA/analog output. If it was reversed (you'd need a different adapter for this, by the way), the output would be DVI, which would have either a digital (DVI-D) or analog output (DVI-A).

Answer (score 1):

All this does is break out the DVI-A connectors on a DVI-I port into a standard VGA connector. Essentially the *[only point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface#Analog)* of DVI-A is backward compatibility with older standards, and as such *electrically* the output is identical to VGA.